# Route attribute hides actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Why `Route` attribute hides|applied to other methods?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Issues/ReportIssue")]
public ActionResult ReportIssue()
```

Action without `Route` attribute stops working

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReportIssue(IssueModel viewModel)
```

`jQuery` returns "Not found" error

If rename `Post` action or add `Route` attribute, all works.  Is there are any priority rules for a `Route` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following code sample -

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Products/Create")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
      ProductCategory category = new ProductCategory();
      category.ProductCategoryId = 1;
      return View(category);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductCategory category)
{
      return View(category);
}
```

And I could see this working properly without any issues. The controller name in my case is "Product", and the below code works if I specify route attribute as "Products/Create" (different from controller name), or "Product/Create". So not sure, why you would be facing the issue.

The Get and Post actions should work without route attribute as well, as they were working. Attribute routing is something newly added in MVC 5, and is there to give more control over the routes. But still, this is not mandatory to use. The traditional routes should work fine.

Take a look of - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx article.

Comment: Could you please check it thru jquery ajax call